# Does my Macbook display port support video input?

Tags: live, mac

I have been reading through all these resources [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort) and [here](http://www.displayport.org/faq/) . But, I don't have my answer.

My question is simply, can the display port on a Mac take video input source?

More Details:  I have

1. Macbook Pro Model 6,2 (Mid 2010) that has a Display Port
2. A camcorder that has HDMI output and NO firewire outputs.
3. A HDMI to Display port adapter.

I want to know if it's possible to use my camcorder like a webcam i.e capture live video for the purpose of streaming. As a primary test, I should be able to connect the camcorder and do a capture using iMovie.

Would this be possible? I am pretty sure input through USB won't work. And from what I have seen there is no easy way to convert the HDMI video stream into firewire. So, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

No, the display port on your macbook pro is output only.

You may be able to use your camcorder as a webcam if it is capable of streaming video over USB or Firewire, though.